# Print values from a spreadsheet with certain value in column

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm developing an application to automate a task in the office where I work. It consists of accessing a spreadsheet with customer data and checking which tax needs to be sent to the customer.

After the code, name, national registration code, e-mail and customer taxation come the taxes, according to the spreadsheet model below;

https://prnt.sc/26tsjdx

If the `x` is marked in the tax column (in the case of the code below, the column `F`:`DAS`) then I take the data of that customer and put it in a named list `integrantes`.

The problem I'm facing is that at the time of a simple `print` to be able to return all the members of the list it returns multiple results and not just the ones with the `x`. Can you help me?

Follow code below:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/temp/fechamento.xlsx')
sheet = wb['fechamento']

lastCol = sheet.max_column

integrantes = {}
codigos = []
nomes = []
cnpjs = []
emails = []
tributacoes = []
das = []


for r in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for c in range(6, lastCol + 1):
        imposto1 = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
        if imposto1 != 'x' or '':
            codigo = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
            nome = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
            cnpj = sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value
            email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=4).value
            tributacao = sheet.cell(row=r, column=5).value
            das1 = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
            codigos.append(codigo)
            nomes.append(nome)
            cnpjs.append(cnpj)
            emails.append(email)
            tributacoes.append(tributacao)
            das.append(das1)
            integrantes[nome] = email

            for codigo, nome, cnpj, email, tributacao, das1 in zip(codigos, nomes, cnpjs, emails, tributacoes, das):

                print(codigo, nome, cnpj, email, tributacao)
```

Comment: What does das1 print in the inner for loop? don't you need `Das = sheet.cell(row=r, column=6).value` to get the column with x in it? (you would have to add that to your zip for loop)

Comment: @AndrewRyan I added it to my loop as you told, but it returns the same results.

Answer (score 0):

in your if statement, you have

```
if imposto1 != 'x' or '':
```

if you are just trying to get the ones with x, it should just be x.

Also you say integrantes is a named list, but you have it defined as a dictionary because of the {}.

Comment: I removed the ```' '``` but it keeps returning multiple results instead of just the ones with ```x```